# dpm function doesn't display results for arrays

Tags: debugging

I need to work over the hook_menu_alter function and I found that the dpm() function is not working for arrays. I have devel and admin_devel enabled. I flushed all cache to make sure the hook is fired.

```
function MY_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  dpm('hello'); // This is printed 
  dpm($items); //This one is not printed at all
}
```

Comment: Try the drupal_debug function which writes to a txt file in your tmp directory. http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/drupal_debug/7

Comment: FYI the exact same code works for me so the problem is with your site in particular...have you tried turning off other modules to see if you can isolate the cause of the problem?

Comment: I have a setup where I get `Array()`, slightly better than nothing but not by much.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_menu_alter()` is fired directly in the same call that flushes the caches - and only once. If you do that via `drush cc all` the result is never displayed.

Comment: This doesn't explain why "hello" is printed, but not the array.

Comment: In fact dpm($items) works if I run cron.

Comment: IMHO cron also empties caches. - where/when does it print "hello"?